# Non-Expiring Direct Link Like When Clicked It Will Download Without Landing Any Page

Tags: url, hyperlink, download

I am just searching for a website which gives direct link which doesn't expire and doesn't have download limit and many features like this.

I just checked dropbox and someother but some of them has expire date and some of them have download limit i want a website which gives non-expiring direct click to download links and doesn't have a download limit.

Comment: Don't just add random tags!

Comment: So, you mean, like any random standard web server…?!

Comment: yeah actually @deceze

Comment: So… there's your answer? Set up a web server or get some equivalent web hosting space somewhere…!?

Comment: i want a website which already exist and able to upload files to this page and get direct link which is not expiring and having download limitations i hope i explained my self great for node.js it is going to retrieve a dll file to folder @deceze

Comment: Well, we can't recommend any 3rd party services here. But… anywhere where you'd host a website, you could host this file.